# Can I freeze water at 100 °C if I add 28 grams NaCl in 100 grams water?

Tags: water, equilibrium, temperature

Can I freeze water at 100 °C if I add 28 grams NaCl in 100 grams water at 20 °C?

I found this [diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Water_(data_page)#/media/File:WatNaCl.png) that says, if I have 28.05 wt% NaCl in water, then the equilibrium temperature between two phases (ice/liquid) will be at 100 °C. Am I understanding it right? I also found this solubility [diagram](http://www.800mainstreet.com/9/0009-004-solub.html) which says that the solubility is ok for 28 grams at 20 °C.

Comment: I am sorry but I don't see how the diagram you linked implies that. If anything, dissolving salt in water should *lower* the freezing point to *below* $0~\mathrm{^\circ C}$. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freezing-point_depression

Comment: @orthocresol What you say is happening only when the wt% is below 26,28%. After this limit the freezing point is increased dramaticly. Look at this diagram  too. [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Water_(data_page))

Comment: It is not a freezing point. It is the point of equilibrium between the liquid and solid.

Comment: @Ivan Neretin What do you mean as solid? Like a crystal?

Comment: If you read the note below the table, it says: "$T_\mathrm{eq}$ is the equilibrium temperature between two phases: ice/liquid solution for $T_\mathrm{eq} < 0 - 0.1$ and $\ce{NaCl}$/liquid solution for $T_\mathrm{eq}$ above $0.1~\mathrm{^\circ C}$". So, your equilibrium at $100~\mathrm{^\circ C}$ is not a water/ice equilibrium.

Comment: If you look at the phase diagram, it is an equilibrium between "liquid solution" and "liquid solution + $\ce{NaCl (s)}$". So, what the table is actually telling you is the solubility of $\ce{NaCl}$ in water (when it is insoluble, it will precipitate out, giving you the saturated "liquid solution" as well as solid $\ce{NaCl}$).

Comment: Yes, like a crystal. Only it's not an ice crystal.